# Prevent back button from poping stack - Navigation component

Tags: android, navigation

I'm wondering how to prevent a click on the back button from going back to the previous Fragment in my app. There is a certain application logic : depending on some state, the user can or cannot go back to the previous screen (they need to do some cleanup before).

The only solution that I have found is to add a callback to the [OnBackPressedDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher#onBackPressed()), which I believe disables the default callback and therefore prevents the navigation.

This seems a little clunky to me, and I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to do it ? Like a `override fun canGoBack(): Boolean` or similar.

Current implementation :

```kotlin
class LiveViewFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                MyTheme {
                    val vm = viewModel()
                    val stageValue = vm.stage

                    if(stageValue == Stage.Editing) {
                        // The callback is automatically dismissed thanks to the lifecycle
                        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner,
                            object :
                                OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                                override fun handleOnBackPressed() { /* Do nothing when back is pressed */ }
                            })
                    }

                    // Main composable
                    MyScreen(vm)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```